# I want to update id having null value to non null value showing in table - sql query

Tags: sql

```
Location | ID

New York | 2
New York | NULL

Paris    | 3
Paris    | NULL
```

For example I want second entity of New York which is NULL ID to value 2.

Comment: How many entities can there be for each `Location`? What if there are multiple non-null `ID`s? Which `ID` should then be used? Min, max, something else?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Location | ID

New York | 2
New York | NULL

Paris    | 3
Paris    | NULL

Comment: And what do you want for Paris?

Comment: There's no need to repeat yourself. Add the missing _new_ info that was requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do :

```
update t
       set t.id = (select t1.id 
                   from table t1
                   where t1.location = t.location and t1.id is not null
                  )
from table t
where t.id is not null;
```

You can use `limit/top` clause (in subquery) if one location has more than single values which are not null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to add a value.  For instance:

```
select location, coalesce(id, max(id) over (partition by location)) as id
from t;
```

This, of course, does it for all locations.  You can limit the particular locations using a `case` expression.

A typical approach to *change* the value would be:

```
update t
    set id = (select max(id) from t t2 where t2.location = t.location)
    where id is null and location = 'New York';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use self join to update (please replace temp_table with your real table):

```
update t2
  set t2.id = t1.id
  from temp_table t1
  left join temp_table t2 on t1.location = t2.location
  where t1.id is not null and t2.id is null
```

Here is SQL fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8f283/9/1

Not sure which SQL RDMS you are using. Below is fiddler for MYSQL:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f3582/1